# Minor rep bug around upvotes when capped when you delete the post

Tags: bug, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

I posted an answer on SO (while already repcapped) that was rapidly upvoted, but then a solid dupetarget was found for the question and so I dupehammered it and deleted my answer. A while later I saw this on my rep page:

[image]

As you can see, it suggests that I got +70 for the answer and then -70 for deleting it. In fact, since I was capped, there was no rep change involved in either answering or deleting the answer. You can see other upvotes just before that answer when I was repcapped that don't have any +10 next to them.

It's not important, but I guess technically it's a bug... :-)

Comment: We're doing some work on rep calcs/rep history displays in a (yet another) attempt to retire Documentation. Should be no impact on the rep *values* at the moment, but history may be a bit wonky. Gonna investigate when back at work on Tuesday.